# Specify cutoffs in ROCR (R package)

Tags: r, prediction, roc, model-evaluation, rocr

I'm using the ROCR package in R to measure performance.
The data I have has thousands of data points (700,000). ROCR ends up picking too many cutoff values and I end up with a performance object which is too large/slow to plot.

```
pred = prediction( values, labels)
perf = performance(pred, 'acc')
```

Is there any easy way to specify which cutoffs the `performance` function uses? e.g.

```
pred = prediction( values, labels)
perf = performance(pred, 'acc', cutoffs=seq(0,1,0.01))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify ROCR plotting function to use only a sample of the datapoints to plot, this will not materially effect the shape of the ROC curve (or any other measure such as precision-recall,etc.), and speed up the plotting significantly.

For example, to use only half the points for plotting add this option in the call to the plot function: `downsampling=0.5`

Excerpts from the user manual:

> Values for downsampling between 0 and 1 indicate the fraction of the
> original data set size to which the performance object should be
> downsampled, integers above 1 are interpreted as the actual number of
> performance values to which the curve(s) should be downsampled.

Edit: For the ROCR package, custom values can be given to plot specific points that we want to show on the AOC curve. But I do not know of any way to specify custom cutoff values to restrict the plot to only those values. If this is required, you could always plot the AOC curve from first principles using line plots.

Comment: This does not answer the questions.

Comment: Which part of the question remains unanswered?

Comment: "Is there any easy way to specify which cutoffs the performance function uses?"

Comment: "Specify cutoffs in ROCR (R package)"